# Example implementation of weak events using .NET's WeakEventManager

Tags: .net, weak-events, weakeventmanager

Is there an example implementation of weak events using .NET's [WeakEventManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.weakeventmanager.aspx)?

I'm trying to implement it by following the "Notes to Inheritors" in the documentation, but it is vague. For example, I can't figure out how to call `ProtectedAddListener` from my static `AddListener` function in my custom manager.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I figured it out on my own following the guidelines in the "Notes for Inheritors" section of the [WeakEventManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.weakeventmanager.aspx) documentation. Here's a basic implementation of `WeakEventManager`. The class sourcing the event is named `PropertyValue` and the event is named `Changed`.

```
public class PropertyValueChangedEventManager : WeakEventManager
{
    public static PropertyValueChangedEventManager CurrentManager
    {
        get
        {
            var manager_type = typeof(PropertyValueChangedEventManager);
            var manager = WeakEventManager.GetCurrentManager(manager_type) as PropertyValueChangedEventManager;

            if (manager == null)
            {
                manager = new PropertyValueChangedEventManager();
                WeakEventManager.SetCurrentManager(manager_type, manager);
            }

            return manager;
        }
    }

    public static void AddListener(PropertyValue source, IWeakEventListener listener)
    {
        CurrentManager.ProtectedAddListener(source, listener);
    }

    public static void RemoveListener(PropertyValue source, IWeakEventListener listener)
    {
        CurrentManager.ProtectedRemoveListener(source, listener);
    }

    protected override void StartListening(object source)
    {
        ((PropertyValue)source).Changed += DeliverEvent;
    }

    protected override void StopListening(object source)
    {
        ((PropertyValue)source).Changed -= DeliverEvent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Microsoft provides PropertyChangedEventManager (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventmanager.aspx) and CollectionChangedEventManager (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.collectionchangedeventmanager.aspx) built-in to .NET.

Comment: Thanks for your example. Athough the shorter implementation will be `((PropertyValue)source).Changed += DeliverEvent;`

Comment: @alpha-mouse: Where exactly is the "weak" in your "shorter implementation"? I cannot find it.

Comment: @Paul Groke: my comment was relevant to the previous unedited version of this answer. Now I have no objections at all.

Answer (score 7):

[Sharp Observation](http://sharpobservation.codeplex.com) is an open source project that has an easy to use implementation. You might want to take a look at their code or just use it as-is.

**[Usage](http://sharpobservation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20Weak%20Delegates&referringTitle=Home)**

> The MakeWeak() method returns a new delegate which invokes the same
>   target as the original delegate, but holds a weak reference to the
>   target so that the listener is not kept alive by the delegate:

```
var handler= new PropertyChangingEventHandler(listener.HandleChange);
observable.PropertyChanging += handler.MakeWeak<PropertyChangingEventHandler>();
```

**[Limitations](http://sharpobservation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Weak%20Events&referringTitle=Home)**

The current implementation has the following restrictions on delegates:

- Return values are not supported.
- Arguments of Out and Ref are not supported.