# emddudley's WeakEventManager's sample

Tags: c#, .net, weak-events, weakeventmanager

I am trying to adapt Michael Dudley's sample code for my own implementation of a weak event manager:

[Example implementation of weak events using .NET's WeakEventManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524597/example-implementation-of-weak-events-using-nets-weakeventmanager/10490721#10490721)

I was wondering where would I put my user code for my own handler? I see this:

```
private EventHandler mHandler = (s, e) =>
{
    CurrentManager.DeliverEvent(s, e);
    return;
};
```

Would I replace the content of that expression with my own custom code?

Thank you,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

For most cases that handler should stay as it is. As a comment on that answer states, the handler declaration isn't even necessary. The following code for `StartListening` should be sufficient:

`((PropertyValue)source).Changed += DeliverEvent;`

If you need to modify the values of `s` and/or `e` before delivering the event you can add that code to the handler you posted. But no matter what, `DeliverEvent` must be called. It loops through and calls `ReceiveWeakEvent` for all registered listeners and there's no way to get at the list of listeners unless you are storing them in your own `ListenerList`. So, basically if you modify the event handler, it must still call `DeliverEvent` or your weak event listeners will never be notified of the event.

If you posted the code you're trying to find a place for, it might be a little easier to help you figure out what you are trying to accomplish and where it should go instead.